# Custom error messages for Groups within the jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, message

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin and i've started to group some of my fields together:

```
groups: {
fullName: "myFirstName myLastName"
},
```

I've also added the fields to the rules section so that they are validated:

```
rules: {
myFirstName: {
required: true
},
myLastName: {
required: true
}
},
```

This works great and produces an error of "This field is required" for the group.

My question lies with custom error messages.  I have the following setup:

```
messages: {
fullName: "Please enter both your first name and your last name"
}
```

Unfortunately the custom error doesn't show, only the generic one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `errorPlacement` for this, and the message should be the same on both, for example:

```
messages: { 
  myFirstName: { required: "Please enter both your first name and your last name" },
  myLastName: { required: "Please enter both your first name and your last name" }
}
```

Then, assuming they have the same IDs here, your `errorPlacement` option would look like this:

```
errorPlacement: {
  var n = element.attr("name");
  if (n == "myFirstName" || n == "myLastName")
    error.insertAfter("#myLastName");
  else
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

The group itself has no message, it's just telling the plugin that they share a message label.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already had my errorPlacement set up.  It turns out that I just needed to set the error message to be the same for the both parts.  Thanks for your help