# jQuery Validate Error Messages for Conditional Required and for Groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been struggling trying to get custom error messages to display properly in 3 different situations when using the jQuery Validate Plug-in.

- Where I have a Group and only 1 member of the Group is required.
- Custom messages for check box fields.
- Displaying an error message when a field is conditionally required.

I've made note of this post: [How to show different error messages based on various conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928470/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-show-different-error-messages-based-on-various-c). Is it perhaps part of the solution to my issues? I've also looked at [Custom error messages for Groups within the jQuery Validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408689/custom-error-messages-for-groups-within-the-jquery-validation-plugin), but it doesn't seem to address the issue of only 1 member of the Group being required and didn't solve my problem.

I'm new to jQuery and fiddles and have a fiddle up which isn't working properly. I suspect its because I don't have links to the graphics used in the CSS which came from the Milk and Marketo examples in the validation plug-in package. The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/cloudmech/myvmb95d/23/.

Here's the code I'm using.

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#00NU00000049YHZ').change(function(){
       var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
       $('#company_information').toggle(checked);
       $('#company').prop('disabled', !checked)
   }).change();

    var $CompHdwDon = $('#00NU00000049YHj'),
    $SchedPickup = $('#00NU00000049YHt');

    $('#w2lForm').validate({
        debug: true,
        rules:{
            company: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    var checked = $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
                    return (checked);
                minlength: 3
                    }
                },             
            phone: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone_group'],
                phoneUS: true,
            },
            Mobile: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone_group'],
                phoneUS: true,
            },
            CompHdwDon: {
                required: checked=true
            },              
            SchedPickup: {
                required: checked=true
            },      
        },
        messages: {
            company: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    var checked = $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
                    return (checked);
                required: "Please provide the name of your company"
                }
            },
            phone_group: {
                required: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
            },
            Mobile: {
                required: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
            },
            CompHdwDon: {
                required: "This box must be checked for us to pick up a donation"
            },      
            SchedPickup: {
                required: "This box must be checked to schedule a donation pickup"
            },      
        },  
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var n = element.attr("name");
            if (n == "phone" || n == "Mobile")
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            else if (element.is(":radio"))
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
            else if (element.is(':checkbox'))
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            else 
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
        },
        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
        success: function(label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).parent().next().find("." + errorClass).removeClass("checked");
        }
        // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<BODY>
<div id="page-content-inner" class="resize">
<form id="w2lForm" action="https://www.xxxxx.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.google.com"> 
</br>
<TABLE >
<TR>
    <TD class="label">This is for a Company:</TD>
    <TD class="field"><input  id="00NU00000049YHZ" name="00NU00000049YHZ" type="checkbox" value="0"  /></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
<!--  If is This is for a Company == false, hide line below. If = true, show line below  -->
    <TD class="label" colspan="2">
    <div id="company_information">
    <label id="cmpnylbl" for="company" class="label" >Company:
    <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text"  class="required" /></div></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
</TR>
<!--- create phone group below and require 1 of the two --->
<TR>
    <TD class="label"><label for="phone">Phone:</label></TD>
    <TD class="field"><input id="phone" class="phone_group" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
    <TD class="label"><label for="mobile">Mobile:</label></TD>
    <TD class="field"><input id="mobile" class="phone_group" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="text" /></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="label">Computer Hardware Donation:</TD>
    <TD class="field"><input id="00NU00000049YHj" name="00NU00000049YHj" type="checkbox" value="1" class="required" /></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
    <TD class="label">Schedule Pickup:</TD>
    <TD class="field"><input id="00NU00000049YHt" name="00NU00000049YHt" type="checkbox" value="1" class="required" /></TD>
    <TD class="status"></TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD class="field" COLSPAN="4"><input type="submit" name="submit"></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
</div>
</BODY>
```

The CSS:

```
body, input, select, textarea { font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; }
img {
    border: 0px;
}

#resize{
    width: 500px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

input { border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: .5em;  }

input.error { border: 2px solid red; }

label.error {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url('images/unchecked.gif') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 16px;
    margin-left: .3em;
}
label.valid {
    background: url('images/checked.gif') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

form table td {
    padding: 5px;
}

form table input {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0px;
}

textarea {
    width: 400px
}

td.label {
    width: 150px;
}

tr.required td.label {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: url( 'images/backRequiredGray.gif') no-repeat right
        center;
}


td.field input.error, td.field select.error, tr.errorRow td.field input,tr.errorRow td.field select {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FFFFD5;
    margin: 0px;
    color: red;
}

tr td.field div.formError {
    display: none;
    color: #FF0000;
}

tr.errorRow td.field div.formError {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#w2lForm .table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}

#w2lForm .label {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  width: 125px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#w2lForm .field {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#w2lForm .status {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 246px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#w2lForm .textfield {
  width: 150px;
}

#w2lForm label.error {
  background:url("images/unchecked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EA5200;
}

#w2lForm label.checked {
  background:url("images/checked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

As a final question, when I get this all working, I want to post it using the servlet shown. Do I need to add what's below to my jQuery, do I need to build an Ajax handler or do nothing at all? I've observed that it seems to submit "as is" when the full url to the servlet is available.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
}
```

Revised jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#00NU00000049YHZ').change(function(){
       var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
       $('#company_information').toggle(checked);
       $('#company').prop('disabled', !checked)
   }).change();

    $('#00NU00000049YHZ').on('change', function () {  // fire on change
        $('[name="company"]').valid();  // evaluate rules on company
    });


    $('#w2lForm').validate({
        debug: true,

        rules:{
            company: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
                    }
                },
                minlength: 3
            },             
            phone: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone_group'],
                phoneUS: true,
            },
            Mobile: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone_group'],
                phoneUS: true,
            },
            "00NU00000049YHj": {
                required: true
            },              
            "00NU00000049YHt": {
                required: true
            },      
        },
        messages: {
            company: {
                required: "Please provide the name of your company",
                minlength:  "Please type at least {0} characters"
            },
            phone: {
                require_from_group: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
            },
            Mobile: {
                require_from_group: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
            },
            "00NU00000049YHj": {
                required: "This box must be checked for us to pick up a donation"
            },      
            "00NU00000049YHt": {
                required: "This box must be checked to schedule a donation pickup"
            },      
        },  
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var n = element.attr("name");
            if (n == "phone" || n == "Mobile")
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            else if (element.is(":radio"))
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
            else if (element.is(':checkbox'))
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            else 
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
        },
        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
        success: function(label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).parent().next().find("." + errorClass).removeClass("checked");
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last question first...

The `submitHandler` callback function is only needed when you want to change the default behavior of the plugin.  The default behavior is that the form submission will be blocked until all data entry passes validation, then it will be submitted to the URL in the `action` attribute of the `form` element.

This code is essentially the default, so this entire `submitHandler` is superfluous and can be left out of `.validate()`...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();  // <- already the default behavior
}
```

However, if you want to submit the form via `ajax`, then you could use it as follows...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   // your ajax function here
   return false;
}
```

---

Secondly, your code is really broken here...

```
rules:{
    company: {
        depends: function(element) {
            var checked = $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
            return (checked);
        minlength: 3
            }
        },
....
messages: {
    company: {
        depends: function(element) {
            var checked = $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
            return (checked);
        required: "Please provide the name of your company"
        }
    },
```

`depends` is not a rule;  `depends` is a property of a rule that simply toggles the rule on and off, and you can't have a key:value pair floating inside of a function.  This should have been causing all kinds of errors.   And you would **never** see `depends` inside of `messages` since the message does not depend on anything... it's simply attached to a rule.

Presumably, you want the `company` field `required` depending on another condition...

```
rules:{
    company: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked');
            }
        },
        minlength: 3
    },
    ....
},
messages: {
    company: {
        required: "Please provide the name of your company",
        minlength:  "Please type at least {0} characters"
    },
    ....
},
....
```

---

Third, what is this??

```
CompHdwDon: {
    required: checked=true
},              
SchedPickup: {
    required: checked=true
},
```

You cannot put `checked=true` as the value when the value of the `required` method can only be a boolean or a function (`depends`).

```
CompHdwDon: {
    required: true
},              
SchedPickup: {
    required: true
},
```

---

Finally, the `require_from_group` method/rule will create a condition where even though you only want one field out of a group to be `required`, the error message will appear on all of them.  [The solution is to use the `groups` option, which will simply group all messages for this particular group of fields into one](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups).  Exact placement of the message can then be achieved with the `errorPlacement` option.

---

**EDIT**:

Your code, for example.

```
rules: {
    Mobile: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.phone_group'],
        phoneUS: true
    },
},
messages: {
    Mobile: {
        required: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
    },
}
```

The methods under your `rules` do not match the methods under `messages`... you can leave some out but you cannot add any that don't exist.

The corresponding `key:value` pairs under `messages` need to match...

```
messages: {
    ....
    Mobile: {
        require_from_group: "Either your regular or mobile phone is required"
    },
    ....
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
CompHdwDon: { // <- this should match the NAME of the field!
    required: true
},
```

This code is doing absolutely nothing because you have no field with `name="CompHdwDon"`.  It only *appears* to work because you have `class="required"` on the checkbox.  In this case, the plugin is using the `required` `class` to set the rule.  Declare rules within `.validate()` or declare them inline, but there's no need to do both.

Change this...

```
<TD class="label">Computer Hardware Donation:</TD>
<TD class="field"><input id="00NU00000049YHj" name="00NU00000049YHj" type="checkbox" value="1" class="required" /></TD>
```

into this...

```
<TD class="label">Computer Hardware Donation:</TD>
<TD class="field"><input id="CompHdwDon" name="CompHdwDon" type="checkbox" value="1" /></TD>
```

---

**EDIT 3**:

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).parent().next().find("." + errorClass).removeClass("checked");
}
```

You do not need to append a period to the `errorClass` object.  It's already built in.  Also when using `highlight`, you would typically also need `unhighlight`.

You also should not need `.find(errorClass)` as this class is always toggling and `highlight` is only firing when the field is invalid.   Also keep in mind that `highlight` is only targeting the particular field being evaluated.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).parent().next().removeClass("checked");
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).parent().next().addClass("checked");
}
```

---

**EDIT 4**:

To immediately trigger the error message on another field when clicking a checkbox means that we need an event handler.  Then we simply fire the `.valid()` method to evaluate the rules on the field.

```
$('#00NU00000049YHZ').on('change', function () {  // fire on checkbox change
    $('[name="company"]').valid();  // evaluate rules on company
});
```

Or this...

```
// assuming your existing change handler is already working...
$('#00NU00000049YHZ').change(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#company_information').toggle(checked);
    $('#company').prop('disabled', !checked);
    $('[name="company"]').valid();  // evaluate rules on company
}).change();
```

Just to be safe, put this `change` handler after your call to `.validate()`.

Comment: Great reply Sparky. The Company field is required depending on whether a check box `is checked`. `CompHdwDon` is a check box which needs to be checked. Same for `SchedPickup`. I've not been able to get a custom message to appear for the Group, only the standard one which I can control the placement of as you've noted.

Comment: @crmprogdev, you cannot set a custom message for `required` when you aren't using the `required` rule.  When you're using the `required_from_group` rule, you set the custom message on `require_from_group`.  See my edited answer.  Take your time and slow down...

Comment: Have been working on this for days trying to solve it myself. LOL! `.phone_group` is a CSS class, not a group created using the add group method. The docs are confusing in that respect. `require_from_group` finally fixed the custom message problem for the Group! Progress! :) Still get the standard message for the checkbox and no message for the toggled box on the Company field when displayed.

Comment: @crmprogdev, well, what is `CompHdwDon` supposed to represent?  In order for the plugin to use this, it needs to be the `name` of the element, yet I see no element in your HTML with this name.  The reason you thought it was working was because you have `class="required"` on the checkbox.  [Maybe study the wiki page along with the docs](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

Comment: @crmprogdev, SO questions should be specific to an issue, not for fixing a whole bunch of unrelated syntax and programming issues.  Anyway, I've pointed out most of the areas where your code is broken and edited my answer with the latest one.  If you continue to have problems, please ask a new question trying to focus it on a specific issue.  Thanks.

Comment: From the code above `var $CompHdwDon = $('#00NU00000049YHj')`. Sparky, I write loads of APEX and spend many hours helping out in SF.SE, but am new to jQuery. I posted what I believed my issues were. I've studied the Docs and other posts I've referenced for many hours trying to solve these issues myself before I posted. If you still want me to repost, will be happy to do so. In SF.SE, doing so would be considered improper. This code is for a Non-Profit Org that needs assistance. They don't have anyone else with the skills or I'd simply hand it off and help with the APEX they need.

Comment: @crmprogdev, I'm not asking you to repost.  I'm letting you know that this situation, with multiple issues in one question, is not typical... and that if you have new issues, post a new question.  As far as the issue in your last comment.  The plugin needs the `name` attribute, NOT a variable and NOT a jQuery selector.

Comment: I thank you immensely for the explanation and your patience. Have put the check box field names in quotes, replacing the variable names. That fixed the problem with the check box custom messages not displaying. Now just need to get the Company error message to display when `('#00NU00000049YHZ').is(':checked')`.

Comment: @crmprogdev, keep in mind that checking that box will only activate the `required` rule on the `Company` field... it will not _automatically_ display the message as there is no validation trigger.

Comment: That's why I referenced the 1st post above at the beginning of my question, wondering if I'd need to implement that kind of solution.

Comment: @crmprogdev, not quite.  We need an event handler.  I'll update/edit shortly.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. I suspected I was close, but not quite there. I had seen your other edit, but knew I couldn't change the name of the field. Thus the use of the quotes since it had a numeric name beginning with zeros. Is also why I'd tried using a variable name previously.

Comment: Have shown the updated code above. Perhaps I've not added the event handler in the correct place because I'm still not seeing an error message when the field is displayed. No errors in JS console. Everything else working great! :)

Comment: @crmprogdev, remove the `change` handler I suggested and move the `.valid()` line up into your existing `.change` handler function as the last line.  Also move this handler to _AFTER_ the call to `.validate()`.  See my edit.

Comment: +1. Spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why my depends was not working. Hadn't realized I had it in the wrong place.